# Multiple Regression independent variables

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, assumptions

I have a relative straight forward question.

Lets say we have a typical multiple regression model. With lets say 3 different independent variables. If one independent variable with its beta parameter has a very low value compared to the other parameters, lets say 0.00025.

Would it be better to not include this variable in the model?

/Peter

$$
\log y = 5.32 + 0.3\log(x_1) +0.15(x_2) + 0.00025(x_3) + u 
$$
where y is measured in pounds and the independent variables are measured in percentages.

Comment: That must depend on what the purpose of your model is, what the scale of that variable is, what the relationship between the predictor variables is.

Comment: okej @mdewey I've added a more specific model, does this help?

Comment: my theory is that we can omit x_3 since, it has such a small effect on logy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no relation between estimated parameter value and it's significance. 
Basically, parameter should be selected based on the significance of the partial r-squared value not the estimated value of the parameter. 
You can try the step wise regression method and build the model.